# How would you optimize this SQL Server 2008 R2 Table

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization

I have a private messaging system for my browser game. When I check most CPU time using queries I see that this table is the most CPU using one. I am not good with indexes, query time optimization. So I would like to get your optimization tips about this table.

Alright now I am going to show you table structure first:

*structure image*

[image]

Alright this following query reads how many unread messages does user have and this query is the most CPU using one since it reads at every page load:

```
SELECT COUNT([Id]) [Number] 
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE [ReceiverUserId] = @1 
  AND [ReceiverReaded] = @2 
  AND [ReceiverDeleted] = @3
```

So what kind of indexes etc might improve my performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different approach that may be viable for your application: don't query the messages table at all when the user isn't explicitly requesting any content, e.g. when he's not in the "messages" section of your game.

try extending your user table with integer valued columns indicating how many messages are there and how many are read already. Every time you modify the message table, you also modify the corresponding value in the user table.

This way you won't need to look through the whole table on every refresh. Note though, that the downturn of this method is some extra synchronization work on the programmer's part. If you've encapsulated the modification of the messages table (add message, read message, delete message) properly, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: actually this is the best idea :) i can do this. it will take some more coding time but since this is the most cpu consuming query it worth ^^

Comment: I don't see how this improves *overall* performance.  It might increase the speed of this one query...but only at the cost of slowing-down your writes to the message table.

Comment: take a look at this image :d http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/6430/howincrease.png

Comment: @kuru kuru pa: It increases overall performance because the query is performed at every single refresh, on every page of the game. Improved program logic should always be favored over premature low level optimization of queries. BTW: Slowdown of posting/reading/deleting messages is negligable in this case, since it's just increasing/decreasing an int.

Answer (score 4):

Why allow NULLs on those columns at all - either it's read or not.  Just default to 0.  Then index on Read/Deleted/ReceivedUser (in that order they will be "partitioned" if you need a lot of ALL READ access, alternatively, if most reads are just for a single user, put an index on ReceivedUser)

What you want to do is see your index be covering.  In your case, you could put an index on ReceiverUserId and INCLUDE columns ReceiverReaded and ReceiverDeleted and it would be covering (for that query).  In the execution plan, you should just see an index seek, since you have a single user.

You could capture the workload and then run it through the index tuning wizard in SQL Server and it would probably make pretty good suggestions.  You need to interpret what it's telling you, of course.

Comment: thanks for answer. actually their default value is 0 so never null. are there any good reference you can give me about index tuning wizard ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG On the Tools menu - you can just tune a specific query in the window, or you can use the profiler to capture a trace and then use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to give you advice on a whole workload.

Answer (score 3):

You always want indexes on the fields you are searching for, so you would probably improve the query performance by adding indexes on [ReceiverUserId], [ReceiverReaded] and [ReceiverDeleted].

Of course the more columns you index, the slower your UPDATES and INSERTS will be.

Comment: do i add 3 different indexes ?

Comment: It all depends on what other queries you will be running against this table.  3 separate indexes will have you covered if you have another query that ONLY looks at ReceiverReaded, for example.

Comment: if i don't have that only looks ReceiverReaded how should i make index ?

Comment: In that case, I would agree with @Cade's answer above and just create one index that includes all 3 columns, in the order you have them.

Comment: for example would this work ? CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_MyTable_8_1547868581__K6_K3_K5] ON [dbo].[MyTable] 
(
 [ReceiverReaded] ASC,
 [ReceiverUserId] ASC,
 [ReceiverDeleted] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Looks good, EXCEPT I would change the order so that ReceiverUserId is first, followed by ReceiverReaded, then ReceiverDeleted

Comment: thanks. actually this was suggested by mssql itself . so order is also important.

Answer (score 3):

A fairly simple rule of thumb in db optimization is to index any column that appears as part of a predicate in a WHERE clause or a JOIN. From your example these would include:

- ReceiverUserId
- ReceiverReaded
- ReceiverDeleted

There are also a number of optimizer tools available that will "observe" your db and tell you what columns to index for best performance.

Comment: Check out the top three links: http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SNNT_enUS377US377&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+server+optimization+tools  I like RedGate's SQ Server products personally but there are other options.

Answer (score 2):

1. Index your search fields (per @PaulStock's answer).
2. Change your tinyint fields to bit fields (default value = 0)
3. Does your body really need to be nvarchar(4000)?  That's HUGE!  Consider much shorter messages (such as nvarchar(300) or smaller -- for reference, Twitter is just 140.)

Comment: changing them to bit never came my mind great idea :D i don't think so message column does affect this query performance since i am not seeking it.

Comment: Size matters...:-)...  For the specific query you listed, it probably wouldn't make much difference (it would still be in virtual table 1), but you mention tuning other queries -- if any of them select the body, you should see an improvement if you can make the field smaller.